# Sentence correction query

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is this sentence structure correct ?

> A society so vibrant and diverse as America’s is bound to dominate.

My basic confusion is that whether to put *’s* at the end of the subject or not.

Another example:

> A personality so mannered and educated as John’s always has a bright future.

Comment: It's not a sentence.  (And, since it's not a sentence, there is no subject.)  And it would be more idiomatic to say "... society *as* vibrant ..."  The apostrophe in *America's* is appropriate, since it's being used an an adjective (a "possessive") for "society".

Comment: thanks for the reply-I edited the question to make it a complete sentence, but it doesn't matter much as my actual query is related to the part which is in the start.

so is the sentence correct ?

Comment: Yes these sentences are correct.  Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: My take: "Anybody with a personality **as** well-mannered and educated **as** John's".... = as John's personality. Somebody who is "mannered" is often a person whose behaviour is very formal, and possibly artificial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. What you've done with the 's is omit the noun that's being modified, i.e.:

> A society so vibrant and diverse as America's **society** is bound to dominate.

You can also omit the 's, which would imply that American is a society rather than having a society (which, to be honest, kind of mean the same thing).

However, the second sentence doesn't sound right to me:

> A personality so mannered and educated as John's always has a bright future.

The problem here is that personality can mean "person" or "characteristic of a person," but not both at the same time. Now who/what can have a bright future? A person, not a characteristic. But if personality meant "person" here, you cannot use it with the possessive "John's," which only makes sense when applied to a characteristic. So changing "John's" to "John" would make the sentence correct, though it still sounds a bit eccentric to me (I'd just go with "somebody" at the beginning).